# Composition Function

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, composition

I need help with a function that outputs a dictionary that contains the composition between R1 and R2 it's output represents R2 ◦ R1

as of now, I have

```
def composition(R1,R2):
  d = {i:R2[R1[i]] for i in R1}
  print(d)
```

this function works inputting

```
R1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
R2 = {'a':'A','b':'B','c':'C'}
output: {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}
```

what I need to work is

```
R1 = {1 : [2, 3], 2 : [3], 3 : [4], 4 : [1, 3]}
R2 = {1 : [3], 2 : [1, 4], 3 : [2], 4 : [1, 2]}
output should be: R2 ◦ R1 = {1 : [1, 2, 4], 2 : [2], 3 : [1, 2], 4 : [2, 3]}
```

what I get is unhashable type list

Any help would be great, Thank You.

Comment: The error you get is because you cannot use a list as a key to a dictionary. What are you supposed to do when `R1[i]` is a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little convoluted to write in Python using list comprehension alone (maybe readability can be a bit improved by using `functools.reduce` to collapse the sublists), but it should be something like this:

```py
def composition(R1, R2):
  d = {
      i: [
          val
          for sublist in [R2[j] for j in R1[i]]
          for val in sublist
      ]
      for i in R1
  }

  print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since both the values of R1 and R2 are lists, you need nested comprehensions to get all the mapped elements in a flattened result for each key:

```
R1 = {1 : [2, 3], 2 : [3], 3 : [4], 4 : [1, 3]}
R2 = {1 : [3], 2 : [1, 4], 3 : [2], 4 : [1, 2]}


output = {k1:[n2 for n1 in v1 for n2 in R2[n1]] for k1,v1 in R1.items()}

print(output)
{1: [1, 4, 2], 2: [2], 3: [1, 2], 4: [3, 2]}
```

Comment: This will break on the first example. It appears needs the `composition` function to work when the values in `R1` are either strings or lists.

Comment: Doesn't "break" really but processing strings and processing lists are two different things.  Although you could create a convoluted unified solution by checking data types.

Comment: Oh...for single-character strings, your code should work, I think. The fundamental issue here is that the OP appears to be using a non-standard definition of "composition".

Comment: this works perfectly! it works for strings and ints. I didn't think to nest the comprehensions as I'm fairly new to python. Thank You Both!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution working in both cases.

In summary, check if the value is a non-string iterable and compose all elements, else just compose the value.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
from itertools import chain

def composition(R1, R2):
    return {k1: list(chain(*[R2[e] for e in v1]))
            if isinstance(v1, Iterable)
            and not isinstance(v1, str)
            else v1
            for k1,v1 in R1.items()}
```

Example 1:

```
>>> R1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
>>> R2 = {'a':'A','b':'B','c':'C'}
>>> composition(R1, R2)
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Example 2:

```
>>> R1 = {1 : [2, 3], 2 : [3], 3 : [4], 4 : [1, 3]}
>>> R2 = {1 : [3], 2 : [1, 4], 3 : [2], 4 : [1, 2]}
>>> composition(R1, R2)
{1: [1, 4, 2], 2: [2], 3: [1, 2], 4: [3, 2]}
```